# Got numbers as categorical data in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I will like to change the data to continuos because i can't work with it properly to do one variable histograms for example.

```
p <-ggplot(quibimdatos) +
  geom_histogram(aes( x = GreymattervolumeValue))
```

The message i got is "Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?"
Im a begginer and i don't know if its a silly question :/

I would like some help please

I don´t really know why is categorical

```
 GraymattervolumeValue   <chr> "460.19412599999998", "466.07900599999999", "461.52331400000003...
$ WhitemattervolumeValue    <chr> "357.84222899999997", "338.24592100000001", "341.24249400000002...
```

Comment: Notice the quotation marks around each number, indicating that R is importing these as character data, which ggplot will treat as categorical. As @Duck suggests in their answer, use `as.numeric` to convert the column to numeric data. You should also investigate why R is importing the data incorrectly in the first place (probably the presence of a non-numeric placeholder value for blank or missing cells?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Your variable looks like `character` format. You need to transform it to numeric. If it is `factor`, you can use `x = as.numeric(as.character(GreymattervolumeValue))`. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code 1
p <-ggplot(quibimdatos) +
  geom_histogram(aes( x = as.numeric(GreymattervolumeValue)))
```

The other option would be:

```
#Code 2
p <-ggplot(quibimdatos) +
  geom_histogram(aes( x = as.numeric(as.character(GreymattervolumeValue))))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could convert the columns automatically with `type.convert`

```
quibimdatos <- type.convert(quibimdatos, as.is = TRUE)
```

and now use the same code as in the OP's post